# reinforcement learning in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, keras, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am looking for a solution to train an AI in NodeJS using reinforcement learning.
So far I could only find solutions in python...

I want an AI to give a buy/sell trigger based on price data and some technical indicators.

Edit: I know python is way better for ML, but wanted to keep everything in typescript. Anyways ended up using python :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.JS isn't really geared up for AI / ML on its own.

You're better off implementing a solution that's either pure Python (you can do a lot with Python - including most of what Node.JS can do), or a solution that involves exchanging the data between the Node.JS part and the Python ML part.

Without any specific info on your implementation it's hard to give an exact answer, but assuming you use the Node.JS part to both receive price data and send the triggers, you could pipe the price data into the Python ML model through something like gRPC and then return the result back to the Node.JS app to implement the logic for sending the triggers.